# Conditional Join or Concatenate in python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 6 columns in excel and I want to join 5 of them; however, in all columns’ cell I don’t have any string some of the have “0”. What I need is: join the 5 column and use “>” separator when the cell is not “0” and when it is zero just keep it as blank. Can you please help how I can do it in python or excel? Following example:

```
The original file is:(C1:C6 are columns' name)
C1           C2          C3             C4             C5              C6
H1           C0           0             L              L                0
H2           R0LL         AB            0              0                0

I need the results like:(C1 and RESULTS are columns'name)

C1                RESULTS
H1                C0>L>L
H2                R0LL>AB
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `mask` to turn `'0'` zero strings into `np.nan`
- When we stack with `np.nan` or nulls, they are dropped
- Now that I've dropped the nulls, I can `groupby` the first level of the `pd.MultiIndex` I created with the `stack`
- `apply` the `'>'.join` function
- `rename` the series and `join` to the first column of `df`

---

```
df = df.astype(str)
s = df.mask(df == '0').loc[:, 'C2':'C6'].stack()
s = s.groupby(level=0).apply('>'.join).rename('RESULTS')
c = df[['C1']]
df[['C1']].join(s)

   C1  RESULTS
0  H1   C0>L>L
1  H2  R0LL>AB
```

Comment: Thanks, But the first line is not work and I think because some of my cells contain only "0" which I need to ignore; however some of the have zero within a string so when I want to mask them it isn't work. For example in cell C2  I have "AB0LR".

Comment: Some of your zeros are numbers and some are strings.  Make them all strings with `df = df.astype(str)`.  Then make sure you are masking with `df == '0')`

Comment: @S.16 I've updated my post and I match your expected output.

Comment: @S.16 Feel free to up vote this answer as well.  I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#use apply to join the non 0 columns by '>'
df['RESULTS'] = df.apply(lambda x: '>'.join([e for e in x[1:].astype(str) if e!='0']),axis=1)

df
Out[90]: 
   C1    C2  C3 C4 C5  C6  RESULTS
0  H1    C0   0  L  L   0   C0>L>L
1  H2  R0LL  AB  0  0   0  R0LL>AB
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)